# OpenCV - How to create webM with a transparent background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing, python-imageio

When I'm using `COLOR_RGBA2BGR` all works fine,
but transparent background of the GIF become black

Example gif url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYOQB.gif

[image]

When I'm using `COLOR_RGBA2BGRA`, then **OpenCV** will generate an invalid video.

How can I write webM with transparent background?

Conversion works here https://www.aconvert.com/video/gif-to-webm/
so it's possible somehow

```html
import cv2
import imageio as imageio

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'vp09')
output = cv2.VideoWriter("video.webm", fourcc, 30.0, (512, 500))

frames_ = imageio.mimread("crazy.gif")

# frames = [cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA) for frame in frames_]
frames = [cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR) for frame in frames_]

for frame in frames:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (512, 500))
    output.write(frame)
output.release()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its all what i have

Comment: VideoWriter can only write 1 or 3 channel images. it's the wrong tool for what you want

Comment: Are you sure that VP9 supports transparency? I'm not an expert on the format, but afaik it only supports RGB and YCbCr color spaces, of which neither has an alpha/transparency channel.